# Retrieve the current language from an editor object

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

Using this code I can subscribe to each editor's events in Atom:

```
@subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable
@subscriptions.add atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) =>
    // any code to do on the editor
```

However, I only want to subscribe to the editor if the editor is using a specific language. How can I retrieve that language from the editor object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite easy! The key is the `Grammar` object.

```
@subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable
@subscriptions.add atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) =>
    if editor.getGrammar().name == "name_of_language"
        // code for this editor
```

Comment: You might flag your answer as correct one for others :)

Comment: I have to wait another day. =P